# reference init twice cpp

Tags: c++, constructor, reference

Hi I'm trying to init an object that have a member passed by reference,

```
    class Machine: public sc::state_machine<Machine, Control>
{
        public: 
        FIFOmidi& _midififo;

        public:
        Machine(FIFOmidi& m_fifo);

};

Machine::Machine(FIFOmidi& m_fifo):_midififo(m_fifo){}
```

and then I want to init it in a Object constructor where it has the same reference object:

```
    class StateMachine{

    private: 

    FIFOmidi& _midififo;
    Machine myMachine;

    public: 

    StateMachine(FIFOd3data& d_fifo, FIFOmidi& m_fifo);
};

            StateMachine::StateMachine(FIFOd3data& d_fifo, FIFOmidi& m_fifo )
        :_sharedfifo(d_fifo),_midififo(m_fifo){}
```

StateMachine has an object of type Machine (I don't use inheritance)

then how can initialize an Object Machine from Object StateMachine ??

because when I declare an instance of  Machine Object the compiler ask me the reference because it hasn't..

Thanx !!

Comment: you would need to specify the relation between StateMachine and Machine so people can help you

Answer (score 1):

Just provide the reference as an argument to the constructor:

```
StateMachine::StateMachine(FIFOd3data& d_fifo, FIFOmidi& m_fifo )
  : _sharedfifo(d_fifo), _midififo(m_fifo), myMachine(m_fifo) {}
```

Comment: Well I thought about Inheritance, but in my case is not, there's an object Machine in StatteMachine and I want to initialize it.. it's that possible(if it's yes how?)? or is it better to use Inheritance in this case?

Comment: @EfremBlazquez Please edit minimal class definitions into your question.